# implementation of a math program using Linked Lists in C++

Tags: c++

Here are the specifics of the problem.

Create an arithmetic program that stores integers in linked list nodes. Each node will store a three digit integer, Subsequent nodes will hold parts of numbers that are greater than four digits long.

For example: 2,101,453,788 would be represented by four nodes, the first being left padded with zeros, resulting in

002

101

453

788

Your program will need to overload the arithmetic operators + and –

Each number input to the program shall have its own linked list and the result of the arithmetic shall be stored in a results linked list. The final result of the arithmetic operation shall be output to the console, with each part of the number listed with its node location.

Example

If we wanted to add 10,000 and 845 the output result would be:

The answer is

Node 1  = 010

Node 2 = 845

Giving 10,845

I am having a a hard time understanding how I will:
  a. pad the left side with 0's
  b. limit the size of the integer to 3 digits

I guess you could call this writers block, I just cant picture the program and am looking for some gentle nudges in the right direction.

I have so far:
  a. created a main class that asks for input from the user in the form of integers
  b. created a struct to act as my ListNode

```
#ifndef LISTNODE_H
#define LISTNODE_H

 #include "stdafx.h"

 struct ListNode
 {
   //the integer data for the node
   int data;

   //Pointers
   ListNode* nextPtr;
   ListNode* prevPtr;


    //Constructor
     ListNode(const int& the_data, ListNode* next_node_ptr = NULL, ListNode*   prev_node_ptr = NULL)
  {
     data = the_data;
     nextPtr = next_node_ptr;
     prevPtr = prev_node_ptr;
  }
};
#endif
```

What I cant figure out is how to modify my struct to adhere to the 3 digit parameter and pad the left side of single or double digit input with 0's.
I thought to store the integers in an array inside the struct so that I can use the index to separate the numbers , but then I thought that I would have to do a ton of string manipulation to get the integer into the array. I next thought of taking the input as a string and counting the characters to determine the number of nodes needed.
Any input would be helpful, sometimes I find it hard to step back and look at the big picture.

Comment: Well you said it yourself: Create an arithmetic program that stores "integers" in linked list nodes. You can't store a integer as 001, its simply 1 but that doesn't change anything since its still the same thing in bytes. Do you see where i'm coming from? You don't need to shift anything just make sure you split it if the value is greater than "999" which is basically 4 digits, if larger than "999 999" it is 7 digits etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rework on your question and come up with a more precise query.

As far as I could make out, you are looking for a way to divide numbers of length > 3 digits into sub parts to be able to store them in your linked list. To do that, divide each of the nos. by 1000 until the dividend is 0. Something like:

```
1000)999999(999   
     999000
     ------
     000999
```

Insert the rem i.e, 999 to linked list.

Since dividend is not yet 0, divide the rem again as:

```
1000)999(0
       0
     ---
     999
```

Now, dividend is 0 so you can stop your loop and go to the next integer. Hope this helps!